# Why does AWS RDS Aurora have the option of "Multi-AZ Deployment" when it does replication across different zones already by default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

When launching an Aurora instance I have the option of "Multi-AZ Deployment", which it describes as "Specifies if the DB Instance should have a standby deployed in another Availability Zone."

However the Aurora documentation states that Aurora already automatically spreads the database across different availability zones?

Additionally, what is the difference between an Aurora Multi-AZ standby and an ordinary Aurora replica. Is that that an ordinary replica can be read from increasing performance whereas a standby cannot be read from?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Aurora replicates your *data* across three availability zones, at the storage layer... but the database server instance, itself, is still a virtual machine running on a single physical machine that is located in a single availability zone.

The Aurora storage layer is outside that instance, and is able to let access continue uninterrupted without data loss, even in the event of the loss of up to two AZs, but the loss of the zone containing the db instance will still cause an outage for you, if you only have a single Aurora instance in your cluster (1 master, 0 replicas).  Loss of an entire availability zone is one of those things that is highly improbable but not impossible.  Your db instance is still a single point of failure when you only have one.

Multi-AZ makes allowance for a complete redundant database instance, in a different AZ, which will automatically take over for the primary within one minute, if it works as designed, in case of the loss of the AZ hosting the primary instance or a catastrophic failure of the primary instance.  It's a second virtual machine, on a second physical machine, in a second availability zone.  It's always running, but you can't access it.  It's in the background, managed and monitored by the RDS infrastructure, but it is only accessible to you in the case of primary instance failure.  The secondary machine can also be used to reduce downtime in the event of a software upgrade or maintenance event on the primary.  When failover occurs, if you are using DNS to connect to your database (as you should), you'll find that the DNS entry is automatically pointed to the secondary.

Contrast this to a read replica, which is accessible all the time and can thus provide a significant performance benefit, by allowing the offloading of reads.  Failing over to a replica involves promoting it to become a standalone master (which permanently detaches it from its own former master) and reconfiguring your application to use the alternate endpoint.  This, of course, is still faster than recovering from a failure in the master by using a point-in-time snapshot to create a replacement master instance.

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/multi-az/

Comment: Thank you. This just removed a lot of misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: This is wrong. There are multiple instances for each aurora replica. Refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Aurora.html

Comment: @PPrasad you are misinterpreting the docs. Auroras replicas *"enable you to scale the read workload for your data over multiple replicated instances to both improve the performance of data reads as well as increase the availability of the data in your Aurora DB cluster"* does not mean **each** replica is made up of multiple instances; the "multiple replicated instances" means only that you can create multiple replicas.  One replica = one instance.

Comment: "but the loss of the zone containing the db instance will still cause an outage for you": This is not entirely true. This will make one of the replica instance the primary, so the outage is limited to the time it takes to convert the replica to a primary, which is typically < 1 min. And even with multi AZ, this switching delay applies

Comment: @P.Prasad, that is a misinterpretation of my statement in the context of the question.  The loss of your instance will still cause an outage for you if it is the only instance you have.  I've edited the relevant section, to clarify.

Comment: Something little out of the context, we still can have a different db instance for the replica right?
Say for my production, I can have a db.r4.2xlarge as my primary and have a db.r4.large as replica/multi-AZ standby ?

Answer (score 28):

Storage in Aurora is replicated across three availability zones. The database head node is a single instance. So, while your data is spread across multiple targets, the head node is not.

When you enable a multi-AZ deployment, we create an Aurora read replica that is available as a failover target. Any Aurora read replicas you create (up to a max of 15 at this time) are also available as failover targets.

There isn't any meaningful difference between Multi-AZ and other Aurora replicas. This is primarily a simplification in the user interface for customers accustomed to using Multi-AZ for other RDS engines.

Comment: So... if you choose Multi-AZ, Aurora just creates a read replica in another arbitrary zone for you?  And that's equivalent to not choosing Multi-AZ, but instead just creating a read replica manually in another AZ, and then that effectively makes your Aurora instance Multi-AZ, even though you didn't pick that in the U.I.?

Comment: I would also like to understand this case. I don't understand if I can have a multi AZ deployment with 0 read replicas. I don't want to pay for a replica I won't be using. I just need a standby replica in case of a disaster, but I'm confused about the options I have.

Comment: @Triynko yes if you "add reader" in another availability zone, your single AZ deployment will be promoted to multi-AZ.

Comment: i dont understand. in a multi-AZ deployment isnt the "standby" inaccesible? meaning its managed by the RDS infrastructure and we only pay for the primary db instance?
but in a read replica, i actually have read access to the replica and i pay the same as what i pay for the primary?
this is extremely confusing. could you clarify please?

Comment: Whether you select 'multi-AZ' when you create the Aurora cluster or 'add reader' later, having 2 or more instances in the cluster makes it multi-AZ. You pay for both instances. You can use the standby instance to serve read-only queries by connecting to the 'reader endpoint'. Aurora manages the automatic failover if something happens to the original instance or the AZ it's in, but you can modify the standby in various ways. (Change its instance class, reboot it, give it a customer DB parameter group...) Other DB engines have their own rules about multi-AZ, but this is how it works for Aurora.

Answer (score -4):

AWS Management console.
The answer to this is straightforward.
You can create Multi-AZ in the management console or ignore it.  Irrespective, the **shared storage** for Amazon Aurora is across three AZ (Multi-AZs) as it's the feature of Amazon Aurora however if we choose the Mult-AZ option then we will also have your instances of Amazon Aurora in multiple AZs.

Thus you should choose the [Amazon console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltida.png) option